# Is this 12+ foot plant a sunflower or hogweed?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I'm trying to determine what this is. The plant is well over 12-feet tall, had huge leaves, and a very thick stalk. People near me say it's a giant sunflower plant, but it hasn't bloomed or shown sign of flowers. My moral ag-knowledgeable friends say it's hogweed, which is very dangerous. Thoughts?

This is the plant [image: the plant].

Here's another picture [image: Here's another picture].

Comment: Looks exactly like a sunflower.  Though I've never seen hogweed in person (I assume you mean Giant Hogweed?), the leaves are much different, as in this picture: https://www.goodhousekeeping.com/home/gardening/a21598753/giant-hogweed/#15323659656822&%7B%22sender%22:%22offer-0-1WjsT%22,%22displayMode%22:%22modal%22,%22recipient%22:%22opener%22,%22event%22:%22resize%22,%22params%22:%7B%22width%22:800,%22height%22:792,%22iframeId%22:%22offer-0-1WjsT%22%7D%7D  Also, if it's a sunflower, it simply may not have bloomed yet.  Mine are just starting.

Comment: Never listen to those friends anymore (concerning plants that is).

Answer (score 3):

The plant in your photo is a sunflower (Helianthus annuus).  The large, heart shaped leaves and stiff, hairy stem are very characteristic of the sunflower as seen in your plant. These form a single flower head on top when mature - about 90 days after planting.  They typically grow to 10 feet in height, so 12 feet would not be unusual.  The tallest recorded specimen was apparently 30 feet in height. Please see links below for more information.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helianthus_annuus#Cultivation_and_uses

https://homeguides.sfgate.com/time-year-sunflowers-bloom-67915.html

http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/prairie/plantx/an_sunflowerx.htm

Answer (score 2):

That’s definitely a sunflower. Hogweed has very large lobed leaves and has more maple or oak look to it. Most sunflowers bloom at different times. For most sunflowers- August to early October is flowering time. Peak is usually September. Hope this helps.